# How can I build an authentication system with react,redux and django without using django default authentication?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I am building a web app in which I have a model in my Django which stores username, email, encrypted_password fields. Now I have asked to build an authentication system using this model with react. I can't use Django default user model.

so, I am asking to you guys, can I do that in react with redux?

I just want to get the Django API with password and email fields. Can I do my rest of the thing in react? if this is possible how can I do that?

In short, I need to build an authentication system without using Django default users model or authentication system with react, redux?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a custom model. [Here are more details about that.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/) More details also [here.](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model)
If you also don't want to use the default authentication system, you will need to build a custom backend (*Do it at your own risk.*).

Comment: Actually, I have no option to use custom model from my manager. I can't use any custom user model. All I need to do is, I have to use my own model to that either in Django API or React Redux front end? How can I do that? Any suggestion?